# wix light.exe cannot find file with type ''

Tags: c#, wix, .net-core

I am trying to build a wix installer that installs a dotnet console app as a windows service.

I've added the following HeatDirectory task to the .wixproj file

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="dotnet publish ..\..\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj -c $(Configuration) -r win10-x64" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <LinkerBaseInputPaths>..\..\MySolution\MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\publish</LinkerBaseInputPaths>
  <DefineConstants>BasePath=..\..\MySolution\MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\publish</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="MyProject.wxs" DirectoryRefId="PROJECTDIR" ComponentGroupName="cmpMyProject" SuppressCom="true" Directory="..\..\MySolution\MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\publish" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath" Transforms="RemovePdbs.xslt" />
  </Target>
```

However when I go to build the Wix project I get the following error

> The system cannot find the file '....\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll' with type ''.

I've had a look at my MyProject.wxs and there are not typos generated by the heat command and there are several .dll's referenced in the same way so I don't understand why it suddenly becomes a problem halfway through whatever it is that is happening.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue please?

**UPDATE**

I put absolute file paths of

> C:\Source\MySolution...

And it is happily building now. Is there a better way of referencing a project? If a colleague checks this out of GIT and tries to build it in a different file structure, they'll end up having to change the file paths...

Comment: Do you have your console application referenced in the wix project?

Comment: @Bryan I did not no. Having now added it I see that I may have had one too many "../" in the directory paths

Comment: you can also simply use $(var.MyProjectName.TargetPath). This will point at the root of your solution, IF you added it to your references.

Comment: @Bryan could you enter your two comments as an actual answer to this question so that I can give you the answering credit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Craig, Do you have your console application referenced in the wix project? Looks like you didn't.

The reason I am asking you this, is if you add your project into your setup project references, you can also simply use $(var.MyProjectName.TargetPath). This will point at the root of your solution, IF you added it to your references.